# To not wrap at 'textwidth' if 'filetype' is 'text'

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

I want to ask Vim to not auto-wrap text at the `textwidth` value. For this, I adopted a function from the following article: [*Vim: Set wrapping and indentation according to file type*](https://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/editors/vim-settings-by-file.html).

The autocmd doesn't work. Why?

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

set textwidth=78
let &colorcolumn = &textwidth
set number
if has('gui_running')
  let &columns = &numberwidth + &textwidth + 2
endif

"""""""""""

function! SetupEnvironment()
  if (&ft == 'text')
    set formatoptions-=t
  endif
endfunction
augroup setup_environment
  " If I open Vim and start typing, or
  " if I save this buffer as a .txt file, or
  " if I open an existing .txt file,
  " I want `formatoptions` will be without the `t` option.
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile * call SetupEnvironment()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tweak settings for a filetype, use an ftplugin (`:help ftplugin`, `:help ftplugins`):

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim

setlocal formatoptions-=t

" don't forget to adjust b:undo_ftplugin
```

There are also `indent` and `syntax` directories for similar purposes; `:help runtimepath` for more.

Comment: This is useful, thanks, but with that function I can set same settings for multiple filetypes, e.g. `if (&ft == 'text' || &ft == 'markdown')`. Also, since I'm not really a developer, my Vim configuration is not very complex, and I prefer to keep everything within .vimrc only.

Comment: @johnc.j. Then use `autocmd FileType text,markdown …` (standard disclaimer about `augroup`), and be aware that `FileType` autocommands are just re-inventing the ftplugin mechanism (and not particularly likely to play well with ftplugins; `:filetype plugin on` enables them, and Vim ships with a good deal of them)

Comment: Thanks, now the `t` option is removed. But I'm still wondering what is wrong with the original augroup. Is using `autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile` should be replaced with something different?

Comment: @johnc.j. It's quite probable that your `autocmd BufReadPost,BufNewFile` is going to be ordered *before* the autocmds in the `filetypedetect` group that are the ones to set the filetype. Therefore, when the `SetupEnvironment()` function is called, the filetype won't have been set, and the check for `&ft == 'text'` will not properly match.

Comment: @filbranden I have just added `augroup filetypedetect | au! | augroup END` in order to disable `filetypedetect` group, but this doesn't seem to make the `augroup setup_environment` work.

Comment: @johnc.j. Bad idea. That would disable filetype detection, which certainly isn’t what you want